# Bash: Append command output and timestamp to file

Tags: bash, shell

Normally in my bash scripts I'm used to do `some_command >> log.log`. This works fine, however how can I append more data like time and command name?

My goal is to have a log like this

```
2012-01-01 00:00:01 [some_command] => some command output...
2012-01-01 00:01:01 [other_command] => other command output...
```

---

The processes should running and writing to the file concurrently.

**The final solution, pointed by William Pursell in my case would be:**

`some_command 2>&1 | perl -ne '$|=1; print localtime . ": [somme_command] $_"' >> /log.log &`

I also added `2>&1` to redirect the `STDOUT`and `STDERR` to the file and an `&` on the end to keep the program on background.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given your comments, it seems that you want multiple processes to be writing to the file concurrently, and have a timestamp on each individual line.  Something like this might suffice:

```
some_cmd | perl -ne '$|=1; print localtime . ": [some_cmd] $_"' >> logfile
```

If you want to massage the format of the date, use POSIX::strftime

```
some_cmd | perl -MPOSIX -ne 'BEGIN{ $|=1 }
   print strftime( "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", localtime ) . " [some_cmd] $_"' >> logfile
```

Comment: Actually it only works fine once, if I do a second command it won't execute at all. Tips? :S

Comment: Are you running it asynchronously?  (eg, with `&`)  How do you determine that it does not work?  Possibly a buffering issue, but this should work ok.

Comment: I'm running like this: `some_command | perl -ne '$|=1; print localtime . ": [somme_command] $_"' >> /log.log 2>&1 &` I know they are not working because I need to `killall` the first one to get the second to do it's job (and also logging). The command causing the issue is a python script (I can deal with that later). But there's a problem... if I start dhcpd in the second place it will output to the console instead of the log file.

Comment: Simple cases of `some_command` work okay for me.  Have you tried with different commands?  Perhaps they are contending for a resource somehow.  But it works for you if you eliminate the perl?  What if you replace the entire perl command with `cat`?

Comment: Forget about my last edit. if I `command >> /log.log 2>&1 &` (my original version, all the commands run concurrently and output correctly to the log file. With your solution or `cat`, the output ends up in the console except for the first one.

Comment: The stderr of your command is not being redirectd.  Try `some_command 2>&1 | perl ...  >> log.log &`

Answer (score 3):

An alternative solution using sed would be:

```
some_command 2>&1 | sed "s/^/`date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'`: [some_command] /" >> log.log &
```

It works by replacing the beginning of line "character" (^). Might come in handy if you don't want to depend on Perl.

Comment: I just tried this and it appears that sed only runs the command once and thus all the lines go with the same time

Comment: Yeah, that shell command interpolation is only going to be run once before sed starts. You can use the `e` command in GNU sed to actually execute the date command for every line of the file. See my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73723738/229247

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install moreutils
echo "cat" | ts
Mar 26 09:43:00 cat
```

Answer (score 1):

something like this:

```
(echo -n $(date); echo  -n " ls => ";  ls) >> /tmp/log
```

however, your command output is multiple lines and it will not have the format above you are showing. you may want to replace the newline in output with some other character with a command like tr or sed in that case.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to [use logger(1).](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_logger.htm)

Another might be something like this:

```
stamp () {
  ( echo -n "`date +%T` "
    "$@" ) >> logfile
}

stamp echo how now brown cow
```

Answer (score 0):

A better alternative using ***GNU*** sed would be:

```bash
some_command 2>&1 | sed 'h; s/.*/date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"/e; G; s/\n/ [some_command]: /'
```

Breaking down how this sed program works:

```
# store the current line (a.k.a. "pattern space") in the "hold space"
h;
# replace the current line with the date command and execute it
# note the e command is available in GNU sed, but not in some other version
s/.*/date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"/e;
# Append a newline and the contents of the "hold space" to the "pattern space"
G;
# Replace that newline inserted by the G command with whatever text you want
s/\n/ [some_command]: /
```

Comment: I have made this answer a community wiki answer in case somebody wants to code ️‍♂️ my sed command. Ideally the command can be easily understood without extraneous steps.